# CodeIgniter Find Exact Word From Paragraph

Tags: codeigniter

I am searching exact word form paragraph from the particular column.

For Example When I search specific then it will return row having specifically word.

```
$this->db->like('jm_judgment',$judgment_row,'none');    
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

Comment: can you give any example ?

Comment: suppose i have a paragraph in column having specifically  word but i am searching for specific word. So i have require a output having exact specific word

Comment: This is my paragraph in Column : It is not merely because of specification of time at or before which the thing to be done under the contract is promised to be done and default in compliance therewith, that the other party may avoid the contract

Comment: When i search specific it will return rows having word specification  or specifically. But i want to return exact word having word specific.

Comment: what if there are multiple exact words in Column?

Comment: show row no issue how much time it is

Comment: In Database Two Row  
1. but when specific allegations are there 
2. eviction and enacts specifically the grounds on the availability
i have to show first row because it has exact word 'specific'

Comment: i have use both,before,after, none in like query but no solutions

Comment: do you want first whole row or just `specific` word from that whole row?

Comment: can you show your entire function?

Comment: i want to return first whole row as a result

Comment: $judgment_row="specific";
$this->db->from('tb_judgement');
$this->db->like('jm_judgment',$judgment_row,'both');
$query=$this->db->get();
return $query->result();

Comment: refer this [ http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-boolean-text-searches.aspx ]

Comment: how to that in my case CodeIgniter can you give some code

Comment: did you try that ?

Comment: yes u have try
$this->db->where("MATCH (jm_judgment) AGAINST ('$judgment')", NULL, FALSE);

It is working But When We Finf Two Word Like Specific Document then it will return all having document is not

Comment: please google it for more or read that article thoroughly

Comment: does not find any solutions

Answer (score 0):

If you want exact match using ci3's like, add a space. Then add 2 or_like to check if the word is first and/or last.

```
$this->db->like('jm_judgment', " {$judgement_row} "); //word inbetween paragraph
$this->db->or_like('jm_judgment', "{$judgement_row} "); //word beginning
$this->db->or_like('jm_judgment', " {$judgement_row}"); //word last
```